# Phonegap Android callback to get token

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, push-notification

I am using the pushwoosh phonegap example and it is working fine. Now I need to retrieve the Token with a callback, but don't know how to do it.
In main.js, I set a variable to receive the return value from PushNotification.js function initPushwoosh()

here is the part in main.js

```
function init() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceInfo, true);
var vvvtoken=document.addEventListener("deviceready", initPushwoosh, true);
var html='<h3>'+vvvtoken+' </h3>';
 $('#mailList').html(html).listview('refresh');

 }
```

and here is the part from initPushwoosh()

```
function initPushwoosh()
{

var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
// CHANGE projectid & appid
pushNotification.registerDevice({ projectid: "xxxxxxxx", appid : "xxxxxxxxxxxx" },
function(status) {
var pushToken = status;
console.warn('push token: ' + pushToken);
return pushToken;
},
function(status) {
console.warn(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
return "failed to register";
});

document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
var title = event.notification.title;
var userData = event.notification.userdata;

if(typeof(userData) != "undefined") {
console.warn('user data: ' + JSON.stringify(userData));
}

navigator.notification.alert(title);
});

}
```

I am running it on my android phone and I am not receiving any returned value. How to make the callback and return token?

Answer (score 0):

`document.addEventListener` does not run the function and return the result. All it does is set the function to run at some time in the future - almost certainly after you try to display the token.

Instead of

```
return pushtoken;
```

try:

```
$("h3").html(pushtoken);
return;
```

Comment: I tried it. It displays nothing. can we use it this way: document.addEventListener("deviceready", var vvvtoken=initPushwoosh, true);